# How to check if Facebook user is the App Admin

Tags: facebook, authentication

Using Facebook API for FB Login, how is possible to know if the user who authorized my application is the application's admin (owner)?

The old days FB return the real FB user id, so it was easy to compare it. Now it returns a number which is not the real FB profile id.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The old days FB return the real FB user id, so it was easy to compare it. Now it returns a number which is not the real FB profile id.

That’s called app-scoped user id.

You will have to use that one to identify users within your app. So you need to get your admin user’s app-scoped id once after logging in as that user, and store it somewhere for future comparison.

There is also the [`/{app-id}/roles`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v5.0/app/roles) endpoint, which you can use to query which users have which role in your app. But that uses app-scoped user ids as well.

If you have multiple apps connected to a business, you can also use the [User Ids For Apps](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/ids_for_apps/) endpoint to be able to match app-scoped user ids across different apps. (You will still have to use the app-scoped id for one of your “main” apps to compare against though; the global user id is not available at all any more via API / to 3rd-party apps.)